# Show that $f$ is bounded at $(0,+\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> Show that a function $f\in C^{1}\bigl((0,+\infty)\bigr)$ which satisfy  $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{4}+\cos f(x)},\, x>0$$ is bounded at $(0,+\infty)$.

My attempt : I would like to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)>-\infty$

We have $-1\leq \cos f =\frac{1}{f'}-1-x^{4}\leq 1$,

then $\frac{1}{2+x^{4}}\leq f'\leq \frac{1}{x^{4}}$.

Let $F$ be a primitive of $\frac{1}{2+x^{4}}$.

It follows that $$(f-F)'\geq 0$$

So we can conclude that  $x\mapsto f(x)-F(x)$ increases on $(0,\infty)$.

I do not see how can I continue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1 + \cos f(x) \geqslant 0$, we have $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$, so $f$ is strictly increasing. For $x \geqslant 1$, we have the estimate $f'(x) \leqslant x^{-4}$, which shows that $f$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$, namely

$$f(x) \leqslant f(1) + \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t^4} = f(1) + \frac{1}{3}\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^3}\right) < f(1) + \frac{1}{3}.$$

To show that $f$ is bounded below, or, in this case equivalently that $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0} f(x) > -\infty$, note that for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $\left(2k -\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi \leqslant f(x) \leqslant \left(2k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$, then $\cos f(x) \geqslant 0$, so $f'(x) < 1$ in those intervals. Thus, for $f(x)$ to increase from $\left(2k-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$ to $\left(2k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$, $x$ must traverse an interval of length $> \pi$. But there isn't enough space in the interval $(0,1]$ for that, so we have

$$f(1) - 2\pi < f(x) < f(1) + \frac{1}{3}$$

for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Brillant! Thanks.